# Using Array.map in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm confused how this code work

```
const sidebar = (
        <ul>
        {
            props.posts.map((post) =>
                <li key={post.id}>
                    {post.title}
                </li>
            )
        }
        </ul>
    );
```

I know that a map returns an array, but how can it return all these tags

```
<li key={post.id}>
    {post.title}
</li>
```

and render it?

I have tried changing it to forEach but it's not working. Nothing displays on the UI:

```
const sidebar = (
    <ul>
        {
            props.posts.forEach((post) =>{
                return <li key={post.id}>
                    {post.title}
                </li>
            })
        }
    </ul>
);
```

Comment: `return` in forEach is ignored, meaning that the callback is of type `Function<void>`. `Array.map`, instead, returns a **new** value, it's far different. The result of your forEach espression is `undefined`. The result of the `map` espression is an array, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once for each
>   array element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

This means if you try to return something in the method executed in `forEach` you are not creating an array of tags.

JSX is expecting an array of tags to be rendered but in forEach you are not creating an array you are just iterating over the array so JSX receives nothing at the end

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering my concern. I know that part, however i want to know how an array of <li> tags are rendered. Because when i look at it, its just like `<ul>[array_of_list]</ul>`. Also, why the list tag does not render when I use forEach even i return it on each iteration?

Comment: JSX is expecting an array of tags to be rendered but in `forEach` you are not creating an array you are just iterating over the array so JSX receives nothing at the end.